# Using e-acute but not s-acute (on Keyboard USA International w/ dead keys)

Tags: 11.04, keyboard-layout

I want to be able to use <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to get the letter `é` but being able to type <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to get the sequence `'s`.

Default my Ubuntu 11.04 came with the keyboard layout "USA International (with dead keys)". Which creates `é` and `ś`. When I set it up to use normal "USA" it creates both `'a` and `'s`.

From Windows (XP) (by using "United States (International)") I'm used to have some kind of *smart* combination of both. This is quite essential in my (Dutch) language where letters like `é` and `ë` are quite common. Anyone knows how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more keyboard: US international with altGr dead keys. IIRC you can then use altGr for accented letters and the normal alt for 's.

[image]

If you want to keep this layout the [Layout description](http://keyboard-layout.software.informer.com/wiki/#US-International) states it is common use to type a **space** between the ' and s.

Comment: Do I have to type `Alt` (+ `Shift`) + `'` to make it work? Or will it work just with `'` + `e`?